# Android: passing reference of a Custom Activity class to custom thread class -> good style?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am new to Android programming and I want to know whether following code snippet can be used without problems or if there are some style issues. The code works at all:

```
public class SelectTeamActivity extends Activity {

    private HashMap<String, String> keyValues;
    private MyXMLHandler xmlHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_team);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        xmlHandler = new MyXMLHandler(this);
        xmlHandler.execute(urlHandler.getUserDataURL());
    }
}
```

Here is the custom class for an asycncron task:

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String pin;
    SAXParser sp;
    DefaultHandler userData;
    private SelectTeamActivity selectTeamActivity;

    public MyXMLHandler(SelectTeamActivity selectTeamActivity) {
      this.selectTeamActivity = selectTeamActivity;
    }

    public String getPin() {
    return pin;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... address) {
    try {
        URL url= new URL(address[0]);
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        userData = new DefaultHandler() {
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("entry")) {
            pin = attributes.getValue("pin");
            }
        }

        };
        sp.parse(yc.getInputStream(), userData);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pin;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView text = (TextView) selectTeamActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(result);
    }
}
```

I pass the "this" reference of the activity class "SelectTeamActivity" to the MyXMLHandler constructor to update the UI after the function "doInBackground" of the running task has been finished.

Is this okay?

I was searching for some other questions which are related to "Update UI within AsynTask Class" but I only found solutions where the class which extends "AsyncTask" is only implemented as an inner class of the UI Activity class. And there accessing the UI is no problem at all.

Regards

Comment: maybe you're going to add more code later, but in what you've posted, you only use the `selectTeamActivity` in your `AsyncTask` to call `findViewById()`.  if that's all you need it for, then you could just pass the task an `Activity` base class reference, which would make the task less tightly coupled to the `SelectTeamActivity` subclass.

Comment: Or it will easier if you pass only TextView reference as you are using activity reference only for TextView initializing.

Comment: @Nate: Yes, thats all what I need. How do I pass only the "Activity" base class reference? getApplicationContext ?

Comment: Just change the constructor in your `MyXMLHandler` to take an `Activity`, **not** a `SelectTeamActivity`, and make the task's member variable also be an `Activity`.  You would then create it in the same way (`new MyXMLHandler(this)`), but now your task does not depend as directly on the specifics of the `SelectTeamActivity` subclass.  and, by the way, I agree with @user370305 that passing only the `TextView` would be better yet, assuming that's all you'll need.

Comment: use context instead of private SelectTeamActivity selectTeamActivity;
then this.context=selectTeamActivity;, i hope it will work.